# simpleForm and dataTables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a table where each row has columns that are simple form fields. I am trying to wrap each row with a form. It should look like this:

```
table
  form
    row
     multiple columns with form fields
     column with a save button
```

I don't know if this is possible, but currently, The form is on the same level as the row, instead of wrapping it. To work around this, I'm just currently using JQuery to look for the closest form. Ugly, but it's working.

Here's an example of what a segment of the code looks like (that's currently working):

```
 - @trackers.each do |tracker|      
      tr
        = simple_form_for tracker do |f|
          td etc
```

This is the only way the form actually shows up on the page.

If I do, as I think it should work, this:

```
 - @trackers.each do |tracker|      
   = simple_form_for tracker do |f|
     tr
       td etc
```

The form doesn't even appear on the page.

I don't know if this is a Slim problem, dataTables problem, HTML problem, or if it's something I'm doing. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derek, the problem is that datables replace your DOM, so it it will be imposible to add your form inside a table row, I think the solution will be wrap the hole table inside a form and add a pure id to each row in a hidden input, so you can tack it. That could be a possible solution, for this to work you should check this link, were it exaplain how to wrap datables inside a form. http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/form.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! You gave a very clear explanation. Great reference too.